# Managing require_once in classes called by Zend and non-Zend classes

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a web Zend framework application that uses registernamespace and Zend_Autoloader_Resource to manage the requires needed for various modules.  I also have a series of simple classes that will be called by cron jobs.  Between the two are a number of classes that should be shared by both.  What's the best way of managing the require_once statements such that neither side gets it knickers twisted?

Clarification:
1. There is no specific error that I'm encountering now, but in my Zend project I notice if I do put in a require_once, it complains.
2. The reason for require_once at all is because I want to use these modules via Zend for GUI, but I also want to use them without Zend, because of it's overhead.
3. Twisted knickers - to get upset over small stuff

Comment: What's the problem? What error messages do you get? What doesn't work? There is no obvious problem to be read out of this not-a-question IMO.

Comment: The best way is to not use require_once at all, simply use the autoloader to require all classes from the correct location on demand. If you have a specific problem (e.g. files being included multiple times, errors due to already-defined-classes being required in) you'll need to provide more info!

Answer (score 0):

Zend makes use of a define APPLICATION_PATH.  It's simple enough to logic around the bits I don't want included in the classes when being called by Zend to say:

```
if (!defined('APPLICATION_PATH')){
    include_once "path/class";
}
```